# UITableViewCell text label jumps on table row animation

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview, ios7

I have a simple expanding table view cell that grows by changing the height returned in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat height = [tableView rowHeight];

    if (indexPath == self.descriptionCellIndexPath) {
        if (self.descriptionCellExpanded) {
            height = self.descriptionCellExpandedHeight;
        }

        height += UA_DEFAULT_PADDING; // 10 pixels
    }

    return height;
}
```

and I set the height on tap:

```
- (void)expandDescriptionRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    if (!self.descriptionCellExpanded) {
        UAAudioExpandingDescriptionTableViewCell *cell = (UAAudioExpandingDescriptionTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CGFloat height = [cell expandedHeight];

        self.descriptionCellExpanded = YES;
        self.descriptionCellExpandedHeight = height;
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

The heights of both the collapsed and the expanded cells are correct, and the text is rendered correctly in the right position, but I am seeing a problem where the text label jumps on animation. Here is a gif of the problem with slow-motion animations turned on:

[image]

As you can see, the cell is correctly laid out before and after the animation, just not during. The text label is a simple `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` with no customizations on frame or position other than `separatorInset`.

How can I prevent the `textLabel` from jumping up upon animation?

Comment: try to add custom label

Comment: Yes, I can get it to work using my own custom label and layout constraints, but I shouldn't have to. I would like to figure out the root cause of the jump